# Laravel 5 How to configure the Queue database driver to connect to a non-default database?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1, we can set the Queue connection configurations in `config/queue.php`.

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

---

```
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
```

---

However, it will only use the default database connection in `config/database.php`.

If I have 2 database, 1 default database `mysql1` in localhost, and 1 database `mysql2` in a remote server, and the Queue `jobs` table is in the remote database `mysql2`, how can I configure the Queue database driver to use the remote `mysql2` database? Please note that the main App is using the default database in localhost.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `'connection'` parameter in `queue.php` to set the correct database connection ( from the ones you've defined in `database.php` ).

```
'database' => [
    'connection' => 'mysql2',
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'expire' => 60,
],
```

I was looking for the same thing and found it in the source code.

NOTE: This will not only read the jobs from this connection ( when running the queue ), but also write them to this connection ( when dispatching a new Job ) .

Answer (score 6):

The best answer here did not work for me, not to say it isn't the best answer for a different issue than mine.  My issue was that Laravel did not cache my config settings.

After going into file \config\queue.php and changing the default driver...

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

The queue was still running on the sync driver.

I then checked the file...

```
    \bootstrap\cache\config.php
```

Around line 30 I saw this...

```
 'queue' => 
array (
'default' => 'sync',
```

...but to connect to the database, it should be...

```
 'queue' => 
array (
'default' => 'database',
```

This resolved the issue...

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Running the config:cache commmand rewrites the config.php file to the current driver settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `$connection` variable in the model. Note that this will only affect `Eloquent` queries and will not work for the Fluid Query Builder.

```
class Jobs extends Eloquent {
    protected $connection = "database2"     
}
```

This would of course require you to have a 2nd `named` connection in your `config/database.php` file that is `'database2' => [...]`.

Comment: If you refer to [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue), when we use this method `$this->dispatch($job)`, it will push jobs onto the queue (onto the `jobs` table in the default database connection `mysql1`). In my case, I would like to push jobs onto the `jobs` table which is in a non-default database connection `mysql2`. My main App is using `mysql1` in localhost, but my Job Queue table is in `mysql2` in a remote server.